# Cython - Efficient options for Python list

Tags: python-3.x, list, parallel-processing, cython, gil

I have this two function in a Cython .pyx code that are called over time in a random manner:

```
cdef double dirac(self,Py_ssize_t i)nogil:
        cdef Py_ssize_t index
        with gil:
            if i in self.muId:
                index = self.muId.index(i)
                if self.muSpk[index] <= self.time[self.tInt]:
                    self.muId.pop(index)
                    self.muSpk.pop(index)
                    return 1/self.dt
                else:
                    return 0
            else:
                return 0
```

```
def addSpike(self,Py_ssize_t muId,double delay):
        self.muId.append(muId)
        self.muSpk.append(self.time[self.tInt] + delay)
        if self.LR < muId:
            self.LR = muId
```

They are part of the same class and have their variables pre defined.

I'm trying to generate a more efficient approach to it but i`m out of ideias. 
I looked for C++ priority queues or CPython API approach but I lack the expertise to implement it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It is hard to help you without a complete working code and additional information. However, if your lists are big, the problem with your code is the bad algorithmic complexity of the `in` operator and the `pop` method. This can be easily fixed in pure python using a dict where the keys are indices and values are timings (note that indicies should be unique). This will be len(muId)/2 times faster in average ! Also I don't think priority queues will help you here.

Comment: Actually the list don't get too big (could be less then 1k), but dicts would not help because i can have repeated muId in the list.

Comment: You can use a [multidict](https://multidict.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or a dict that would contain [deques](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) to deal with duplicates since elements are removed in-order. With 100~1000 elements, you should get a good speed-up.